# Vim doesn't autoindent when pasting from system

Tags: vim, clipboard

I am trying to paste text from the system clipboard into vim, and it is not auto-indenting. I highlight then middle click in a terminal window, and any newlines are not indenting to the level where I pasted. Auto indent is working when typing normally.

I have tried:

- Pasting after `:set paste` and `:set nopaste`
- Pasting while in insert mode and normal mode
- Copying and pasting using `Ctrl-Shift-C` and `Ctrl-Shift-V`

I have set these in my `.vimrc` file:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set noexpandtab
```

Yank and paste are working normally: `2yy` then `p` pastes with original indentation, and `]p` pastes with correct new indentation. My vim doesn't have system clipboard functionality like `"*p` (`:echo has('clipboard')` returns 0), but I don't have permissions to re-install vim.